# Intraday and Intra-Week Pattern of Implied Volatility in FX market

Tags: implied-volatility

Q1. How does implied vol changes from market opening time to market close time? I have read that it decreases during the day i.e. it opens high and closes low. what is intuitive and mathematical explanation for the same?

Q2. How does implied vol changes from Monday to Friday? I have read that it starts low on Monday and closes high on Friday. What is the proper explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: interesting question. it may have have something to do with the realized volatility of  equities during the day. ihat has its own specific shape  during the day but I don't know how it relates to the implied.

Comment: How do you calculate time to expiry for the implied vol? Do you for instance take saturday and sunday into account?

Comment: Let's say you don't count saturdays and sundays into time to expiry. Let's further say that price relevant economic information anyway arrives during saturdays and sundays. Then your estimated implied volatility would be too high on fridays as you would use an effectively too short time to expiry in your calculation.

Comment: Q1. What would happen if an option is issued on Monday and Friday of the same week is its expiry date? Will IV follow the same pattern and will its IV be high on Friday compared to Monady?

Comment: Yes, maybe that's the essence of your question, is there a IV pattern day-counting issues aside?

Comment: Is there a particular security you are wondering about? Or a particular market? Or for the global universe of securities? Also volatility with what time interval (minute by minute, hour by hour...)?

I could plot that data for you and show you how volatility changes over time but I'll need more information from you.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out. I am looking for 1. How implied volatility varies from Monday to Friday for FX options with maturity more than 1 week. 2. How implied volatility of FX options varies from Monday to Friday for options issued on  Monday and expires in Friday of the same week?